# How to work-around "Object required" error when adding a variable in an ATL Dialog

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, atl

I'm using Visual Studio .NET 2003 to develop a COM ATL application in unmanaged Visual C++.

I've created a ATL Dialag and whenever I try to add a variable for a control the wizard thorws the message "Object required".

I've tried the following alternatives:

- Right click in the control to call
  "Add variable" from there: this way
  the wizard does not thorws the
  message but the variable is not
  created.
- [This post](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=441693), but it is
  for VS2005.

Does anyone knows any work-around-around for this problem? Or what the wizard actually does so I can do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323515) may helps. This is while adding the class. Same thing may apply for adding variables.

Comment: Thanks! but unfortunately it is not my case. I've tried in Windows Vista and Windows XP. I've also tried restarting the IDE. Moreover, in my case the error arises in only one particular wizard.